# Using drush to delete nodes

Tags: drush, nodes

Can drush delete individual nodes? And if so, can use drush to delete all nodes of a particular Content Type?

*Background info:* I'm not trying to delete the Content Type but all *nodes* of that type. Also this site is a dev install with a copy of a working database. I'm experimenting with feeds and imports and creating tons of nodes form RSS imports.